# AngularJS - How to unit test a directive that manipulates HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, bdd, karma-runner

Good evening, guys.

I'm having a bit of a problem testing a directive that takes an id and disables all the inputs that are children of it.

I mean, if I have a div with an id "id-from-my-div" and I have an input inside of this div, when the user clicks on the directive element, I'd disable the input. For example:

```
<div id="id-from-my-div">
  <input type="text" />
  <button i-disable-stuff="id-from-my-div"></button>
</div>
```

Here's the directive code:

```
myApp.directive('iDisableStuff', [function()
{
    var _link = function(scope, element, attrs)
    {
        element.on('click', function()
        {
            var _id = '#' + attrs.iDisableStuff;

            var _toDisable = _id + ' input, ' +
                             _id + ' button, ' +
                             _id + ' textarea';

            $(_toDisable).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        })
    }

    return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: _link
           }
}])
```

And here's how my test looks like:

```
describe('iDisableStuff', function()
{
    var _scope, _element, _compile, _html;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector)
    {
        _scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
        _compile = $injector.get('$compile');

        _html =     '<div id="test123">' +
                        '<input type="text" />' +
                        '<input type="number" />' +
                        '<input type="date" />' +
                        '<input type="time" />' +
                        '<input type="button" />' +
                        '<textarea></textarea>' +
                        '<button id="click-me" i-disable-stuff="test123"></button>' +
                    '</div>'

        _element = angular.element(_html);

        _compile(_element)(_scope);

        _scope.$digest();
    }))

    describe('checks if the click is disabling inputs', function()
    {
        it('should disable all the inputs when clicked', function()
        {
            _element.find('#click-me').eq(0).click();

            expect(_element.find('#test123 input').attr('disabled')).toEqual('disabled');
        })
    })
})
```

And this fails with:

```
Expected undefined to equal 'disabled'.
```

And if I 'dump' _element.find('#test123 input'), it'll show my '_html' with all the inputs not disabled.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `_element.find('#test123 input')` actually searches *inside* the element, but the selector you have is `#test123 input`. There is no element with an id of "test123" within your element node, since the element node itself has that id.

If you were to replace it with just `_element.find('input')`, that should work.

Comment: Also, you are using `.prop('disabled')` and `.attr('disabled')`. It's probably best to be consistent, and `.prop()` is best. In fact, when setting the disabled property, use `true` as the second argument, rather than `'disabled'`.

Comment: Hello, Greg! Thanks for the quick answer. 

The thing is, since my _html variable has a div that has an id "test123", angular/jquery should look inside of it, in this case, look for input selectors. 

When I dump _element.find('#test123 input'), it does show everything I have inside my _html var, but the selectors aren't affected by the click - they should be disabled.

Comment: Just changed from `.attr()` to `.prop()`, but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "dump"? Do you mean you did `console.log(_element.find('#test123 input'))`? If so, maybe you got confused by the output which is an object with properties like `context`, `prevObject` and so on? You will see everything in your `_html` property in `prevObject`, but you should see that the actual `length` property of the root jQuery object that gets logged should be 0. Correct?

Comment: dump is like a console.log that you can use if you're using karma. Here's the output, by the way: 

`{length: 0, prevObject: {0: <div class="ng-scope" id="test123"><input type="text"><input type="number"><input type="date"><input type="time"><input type="button"><textarea></textarea><button id="click-me" i-disable-stuff="test123"></button></div>, length: 1}, context: undefined, selector: '#test123 input'}`

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about dump. Notice how the `length` is 0? That means it didn't find anything that matched the selector. You should ignore the contents of the `prevObject` property, that is just so jQuery maintains the selection you ran the `.find()` on so you can get back to it if need be (e.g. using `.end()`).

Also, note that when using `.prop()` or `.attr()` as a getter to retrieve the value, it will only return the value for the first element in the selection, which would be the first `input` inside `div#test123`. You will probably need to use `.each()`...

Comment: Did you try changing the selector for `.find()` to just "input", by the way? That should work.

Comment: Nice reminder, I really forgot about `.each()` on this one, but since I'll need to have the first one disabled as well, it's already showing it's not working. About changing the dump(_element.find('#test123 input')) to dump(_element.find('input')), here's the result:

Comment: `{0: <input type="text">, 1: <input type="number">, 2: <input type="date">, 3: <input type="time">, 4: <input type="button">, length: 5, prevObject: {0: <div class="ng-scope" id="test123"><input type="text"><input type="number"><input type="date"><input type="time"><input type="button"><textarea></textarea><button id="click-me" i-disable-stuff="test123"></button></div>, length: 1}, context: undefined, selector: 'input'}`

Comment: I think the rest is up to you from here. You can see that changing the selector to "input" did correctly return the inputs you were after. I would personally next dump out the disabled property of each matched input, as by using `.prop()`, you may not see a visible attribute change in the markup.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try to figure out what's going on, since my `.click()` does call my directive function, but my html/container and its inputs are not being affected in the tests. The thing is: everything is working fine when I'm testing on the real browser. But anyway, thanks for the tips and patience, Greg! If I come up with a solution, I'll post it.

Comment: One final thought: the reason it works in a real browser is that when you call `$(_toDisable)` in your directive link function, it can correctly search the entire DOM for matching nodes because everything is already attached to the DOM tree. In your test, though, all you have is an in-memory DOM node that hasn't been added to the DOM and thus that `$(_toDisable)` in the link function won't see it, and I'm not sure what it would find, if anything. Perhaps you could just test that the correct selector gets set somehow, and not test every little detail?

Comment: What do you mean by "test that the correct selector gets set somehow"?

Comment: Expose your `_toDisable` variable somehow, maybe using the jQuery `.data()` capability, and then test that it was set correctly, since if the selector was set correctly, then you can all but guarantee that the directive performs correctly, given the one line that you can't test easily, `$(_toDisable).prop('disabled', true)` is so trivial and almost impossible to screw up unless the `_toDisable` part is wrong.